# Can you connect two questions with a comma?

Tags: grammar, questions, commas, question-marks

I find myself doing this sometimes.  Part of me questions whether it looks totally correct.

```
Would that be ok, what type of ticket do I need?
```

Should it be the crazy looking version I found on line:

```
Would that be ok? what type of ticket do I need?
```

Should it be two sentences:

```
Would that be ok? What type of ticket do I need?
```

Thanks, for you advice.

FYI: The context was getting an approval.  And then I also wanted to know what type of ticket would be needed.  Assuming it was allowed.

Comment: Any time you start a new sentence, you capitalize the first word.  If you end the first part with a question mark, you're starting a new sentence, and therefore "what type of ticket..." should be capitalized.

Comment: I saw online you can have question mark in the middle of sentences.

Comment: You can't put a sentence-ending punctuation mark like a question mark in the middle of a normally punctuated sentence.  I would be very curious to see what you saw online, if you can find it again.

Comment: @stangdon Here is a link - https://www.scribendi.com/academy/articles/question_mark.en.html#:~:text=It%20might%20look%20awkward%20to,of%20fiction%2C%20primarily%20in%20dialogue.

Comment: I've never seen that rule before. I note that, in their example, the second question begins with _and_, so it isn't a new sentence. If I was writing that in dialogue, I would include a dash before _and_.

Comment: I have never seen that usage anywhere else, and I am very suspicious of it.  The author is unnamed and does not cite any sources, and there are no "laws of grammar" for English: English is described by how people commonly use it, and that kind punctuation is not common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only when you make a list of more than 2 items can you use commas, but you must use 'and' to join the final two items.

For example:

> What time does it start, where is it, and do I need a ticket?

Just two questions would require you to use 'and' and would not need a comma:

> Where is it and what time does it start?

However, your two questions don't seem to fit well together. Maybe more context would make that clearer to me, but we would only normally group questions together in this way as a means of gathering all the information needed to achieve one overall purpose. In my example, all three questions are about attending an event. But your first question of "*would that be okay?*" could presumably attract the answer "no". So what if 'it' isn't okay? Will you still need to ask about tickets? They just sound like two questions one would not join together, unless I'm missing something. If your second question depends on the answer to the first question being positive, then most people would ask the questions separately - check it is 'okay' first, and then ask about the ticket.

Comment: I suppose you could say something like *Would that be alright, and if so what type of ticket shall I get you?*

Comment: Yes WS2, that is context I meant.

Comment: Thanks, for both your help.  I'll use an and between two questions.  I also like the "if so."

Comment: Thumbs up for the Oxford comma.